# Call JSP from Plain Java application and get response back to it

Tags: java, jsp

I have a Java file which contains main method. I want to call a JSP page from that java file, which will call another java file and get the result back to my main Java file. The second java file will get results from database.

**Flow**

***Main Java class*** <---> **Jsp** <----> **Another Java class**

My Work (Edit):

Main Java file:

```
  public String someMethod() throws Exception 
  {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();;
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        String result=null;

        HttpPost method = new HttpPost("url to jsp");
        method.setHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
        int statusCode = 0;
        try
        {
            List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameterName1", "value"));
            urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameterName2", "value"));
            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
            HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(method);
            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
            {
                //do some work
            } 
            else 
            {
                //do some work
            }
            return statusMessage;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
```

My jsp :

```
<%
   String parameter1 = (request.getParameter("parameterName1"));
   String parameter2 = (request.getParameter("parameterName2"));
%>
```

By this method the Jsp is been called, but I am not getting parameter values in the jsp file (getting null values). But if I append parameters  in the url itself (another method called as Url Rewriting), I get those values in the jsp file. Am I doing anything wrong? I want to get those parameter values by the method I have provided in the code. can anybody help?

Comment: JSP is a view technology, while it seems that you want to make a web call from a Java main method somewhere.  Have you considered creating a web service for this (this is the approach I would take here)?

Comment: I don't know much about webservice(Only theory).

Comment: Start by looking at this page: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in a little different way. Instead of content type as "application/xml", i used "application/json" and passed a parameter in a map.

Main Java file:

```
public String someMethod() throws Exception 
{
    Map reqMap = new LinkedHashMap();//contains your parameter and values
    reqMap.put("parameter1", "value1");
    reqMap.put("parameter2", value2);
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();;
    HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
    String result=null;

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("url to jsp");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    int statusCode = 0;
    try
    {
        JSONObject holder = new JSONObject(reqMap);//convert it to jsonObject
        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(holder.toString());//convert it to StringEntity
        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);//set the entity
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode(); 
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
        {
            //do some work
        } 
        else 
        {
            //do some work
        }
        return statusMessage;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In jsp:

```
<%
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    try 
    {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } 
    finally 
    {
        reader.close();
    }
System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
%>
```

you will get a string. convert it into JsonObject as

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
```

and do the further work.

*Addition*: If you want you can pass List instead of Map (reqMap) in the request as per your requirement. Then in jsp you have to convert the string as

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringBuilder.toString());
```

*Note* : do include jar for Json in your project.

For response from jsp back to main class I have added an expression tag (you can do whatever you want) and returned a map in json format.

```
<%= gson.toJson(somemap) %>
```

after getting the response in httpResponse you can do something like this

```
InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
String result = bufferedreader.readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

JSP is meant to run under a servlet container e.g. Tomcat or Jetty. That's because that JSP might have complex code which relies on container services:  access to http sessions, inclusion of other jsp fragments, SSL etc. 
So personally I'd just run it in the safe intended way - either on a separately installed Tomcat, or an embedded one (=launched from my Java code, see note below) . Then I'd invoke it from java using apache HttpClient (which sends out HTTP requests just as if it were a browser).

Note - if you want to use an embedded container you could lookup: http://java.dzone.com/articles/embedded-tomcat-minimal
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/embedding-jetty.html
Note it might require some tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try with the following code for Java Class --> JSP**

```
URL url = new URL("<JSP page url>");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
```

For more details about URL read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

**For JSP --> JAVA Class**

Step 1 : Import your class in Jsp `<%@ page import="mypackage.MyJavaClass" %>`

Step 2 : Invoke your method and get the values return from called method

```
<% MyJavaClass c = new MyJavaClass()
 c.your_method();
%>
```

Or 
If you know about JAVA Beans, I would suggest you to use JAVA Beans.

```
<jsp:useBean id="cust" class="mypackage.MyJavaClass" scope="session"/>
```